# Can a mourner/avel learn Torah on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, torah-study, mourning-aveilus

If I'm not mistaken a mourner in the 1st 7 days, during the Shiva cannot study Torah (except for mourning-related Torah study) as it brings joy to a person.
Firstly is this Halacha or a Minhag?

However does this apply on the Shabbat as well?

Please provide sources if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is Halacha and is brought in Shulchan Arukh YD 384.

It applies on Shabbat just like all other mourning restrictions: only when not done publicly. So learning Gemara in your house is prohibited, but getting an Aliyah that you get every week and people would notice your not getting is permitted. (YD 400)